# WSO2 throws EmptyStackException while trying federated login

Tags: spring-boot, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have two WSO2 Identity server running in same machine, one is identity server another on the federated identity server to replicate federated login, When i access from client spring boot applicaiton  Identity server throws the following exception. Need some advice..

> ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/oauth2].[OAuth2Endpoints]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [OAuth2Endpoints] in context with path [/oauth2] threw exception java.util.EmptyStackException
>           at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)

My WSO2 version is : 5.9.0

Detailed logs:

> ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/oauth2].[OAuth2Endpoints]} - Servlet.service() for servlet [OAuth2Endpoints] in context with path [/oauth2] threw exception java.util.EmptyStackException
>           at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
>           at java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder.endTenantFlow(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:1295)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.context.PrivilegedCarbonContext.endTenantFlow(PrivilegedCarbonContext.java:75)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.authorize(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:250)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor246.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>           at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
>           at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
>           at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:193)
>           at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103)
>           at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
>           at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
>           at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:225)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>           at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.filter.AuthorizationHeaderFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationHeaderFilter.java:85)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:100)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:74)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:116)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestEncodingValve.invoke(RequestEncodingValve.java:49)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could locally reproduce this issue in IS 5.9.0 when following the below steps:

- Configure a OAuth SP in the primary IS
- Configure a SAML Identity Provider in the primary IS
- Configure a SAML Service Provider in the federated IDP.

When the OAuth Service provider in the primary IS  calls /oauth2/authorize endpoint, the above error logs can be obtained in the console.

There is a similar issue reported [git hub](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/6666) in IS 5.9.0 for SAML outboud federation and it is fixed with the latest samlsso authenticator in the latest IS (IS 5.10.0-beta).

As mentioned in the git issue, this error occurs only when you **Enable Authentication Request Signing** However, signing the authentication request is not mandatory unless you are expecting to extra-harden the security in the SSO process.

So as a workaround, you can disable signature validation in IS 5.9.0 as given below.

**In Primary IS side:**

- Go to IS server mgt console and open the configurations of the
  identity provider  Go to the tab Federated Authenticators Configuration
  -> SAML2 Web SSO Configuration and open the configuration there.
- Untick **Enable Authentication Request Signing** option. 
  [image]

**In Federated IDP side** :

- Go to Federated IDP mgt console and open the configurations of the service provider
- Go to the tab Inbound Authentication Configuration -> SAML2 Web SSO Configuration and open the configuration there.
- Untick **Enable Signature Validation in Authentication Requests and Logout Requests** if it's ticked previously.

[image]